# How to set correct type on Observables?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

New to observables/angular 2.  Got things updating correctly on my component, but I'm getting this error from typescript:

> Argument of type 'StoreItem[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string'.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to set the correct type?

```
//store.item.interface.ts
  export interface StoreItem {
  id?: number;
  qty?: number;
  nameList?:Array<string>;
  title: string;
  price: number;
}


//cart.service.ts

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { StoreItem } from '../store.item.interface'

@Injectable()
export class CartService {
  private _subject = new Subject<string>();
  private _cartList:StoreItem[] = [];

  cartList$ = this._subject.asObservable();


  addItem(item:StoreItem){
    this._cartList.push(item)
    this._subject.next(this._cartList)

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just set the correct type for the Subject (assuming you want to emit the entire `_cartList` array):

```
private _subject = new Subject<StoreItem[]>();
```